# angular apex-Distributed Columns chart - I want to get clicked column index

Tags: angular, apexcharts

I got index using click function but when I assig value to the property that assigned value not reflected in the html page

```
     events: {
      click: (chart: any, w: any, e: any) => {
        debugger;
        this.currentClickValue = e.dataPointIndex;
      }
```

I am trying to display the "currentClickValue" but now working.

Comment: sample code available in : https://codesandbox.io/s/apx-column-distributed-forked-tuny94?file=/src/app/app.component.ts